wrapping C-macro calls in inline function templates is difficult in mixed code
I am working with a codebase which is written in C and C++. About 50-50.
Due to this, there are a lot of macros in c-headers which act as functions,
e.g:
#define FOR_EACH_ITEM(item, func) \
  while((item)) { \
     func               \
     item = item->next; \
  }

Due to their age, these macros are well established (fellow programmers are familiar with what they do), so they inevitably leak into C++ code.
Some macros are way too large, so ideally, it would be better if they were written as inline/function templates.
I see 3 tactics:

copy each macro as an c++ inline function template as well

C++ code could use the inline functions.
C code can still use the macros
(+) Debugging possible for C++.
(-) code duplication.


make c++ inline function templates that use (wrap) the macros

C++ code could use the inline functions.
C code can use the macros
No debugging possible.
No duplication


convert every macro to c++ inline function

C++ code will use the inline functions.
C code will call the inline functions via (non-inline) extern "C" functions
(+) debugging possible.
(-) performance and expression freedom in c files will take a serious hit.



The C-files are old, and we sometimes convert them to C++,
but this will take many years (>10) to effectively change, and the macro usage will keep on growing.
How is this issue typically tackled in the industry?
Is there an alternative solution that I am not seeing?

What C-Standard are you using? Just because there is inline in C since C99 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/inline).

@David, interesting info, thanks. I could press for moving into C99, but inline is not sufficient for replacing such macros. It is the template that will enable me to replace them

You're right of course, the given example is not possible to inline in C. In C such macros are very common for exactly that reason. On the other hand, is it that much that can be saved by such macros? Maybe it doesn't hurt to write out that small loop for example. Can the ones "way too large" be divided into multiple macros / functions?

You miss 4. Don't change it. Seriously, as long as it is not broken it isnt broken.

they inevitably leak into C++ code would a code review catch that?

Or could you move them to a header file that C++ code does not #include?

@David ( is it that much that can be saved by such macros? ): the macros are in effect functions. They encapsulate a way of doing something (e.g. looping a linked list). If this changes in the future (e.g. if it is not a list anymore), you don't want to refactor thousands of occurrences.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai ( don't change it ): Indeed. But using macros is against all C++ coding guidelines. Replacing them with function templates is the instruction that the guidelines give. I cannot follow this guideline because of C. I was wondering if anybody else has stumbled on this before

How C-code are mixed with C++-code? Do they call each other? Are they in different lib?

@catnip of course I can forbid people calling the macros in C++, but then what should they call instead? That is my question. Should I duplicate the macro code?

@Jarod42 they are in the same lib. C may call c++ functions declared as extern "C".
C++ can call C functions

item = item->next; makes me thing that you should have std::list<Item> in C++; having a (template) function to iterate on it seems, at best, a temporary solution anyway.

How big is your codebase?  I had a very C-like C++ app.  I swept through the whole thing and converted it to modern C++ and never looked back.  Maybe you can persuade management to take the hit.

@catnip currently >25M lines. C++ compiles 10x slower once you start introducing stl. So nobody is eager to change it just for the reason I mentioned. I reckon it will take 10 years to change it.

@Jarod42 list is just an illustrational example. However, the C code is >15 years old, and nobody will change its structures unless there is much to gain.
